# Microsoft Word - RTL text is reversed (Hebrew)

Tags: microsoft-word, regex

I have this file that was exported from a DOS program, as a weird text file.
Opening it with Microsoft Word, asks me to set an encoding - I set `Hebrew(MS-DOS)`

The file is formatted RTL, with most things correct and in place, but the text is backwards.

I tried changing the alignments and stuff for it, but it doesn't change it.

Backwards means: שלום is written as םולש.

Is there a way to make Word reverse all the words?

I know how to work with regular expressions, so I thought perhaps I can regex replace, so tried:

`[א-ת|"|'|\.]*?` which works if I copy some text to notepad, but doesn't work well at all in word.

Saving the file as a text file, results in a weird encoding.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the encoding of the text file created by your commandline application (DOS program) is not Hebrew(MS-DOS) (aka [CP 862](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_862)). Hence, when you opened it with Word and selected Hebrew(MS-DOS) as encoding, it got read incorrectly. This seems plausible, since CP 862 stores text in visual order.

If you can properly determine the character encoding of the "weird text file", you can set the correct encoding when opening it with Word, and the resulting text should look ok. You might find the output encoding in the documentation of your DOS program, or you might be able to detect the encoding using Notepad++ (although it can be wrong). As a last resort, you could just try opening the file in Word and try a few different, common encodings.